# Accessing an element of my json response in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a response with two jsons, exactly like this -

```
{
  "redirectUrl": "http:\/\/lumoslocal.heymath.com"
}, 
{
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

I need to redirect on getting the response to the `redirectUrl`. Something like `window.location.href = response.redirectUrl`. But it's not working. Possibly because of two json in my response. How do I use the 'redirectUrl' of my first json?

Comment: Can you please show us the your code? Including the way you're handling requesting & receiving the json?

Comment: I have a response String authResp = "{"redirectUrl":"http:\/\/lumoslocal.heymath.com"}, {"status":"SUCCESS"}". I then wrap it up in a ResponseEntity with respEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(authResp); . This respEntity is my ajax response to the client.

Comment: ***I have a response String authResp = "{"redirectUrl":"http:\/\/lumoslocal.heymath.com"}, {"status":"SUCCESS"}"*** - Wrapped in quotes, Are you sure it is a valid JSON?

Comment: Two valid jsons separated by a comma(,). Am I wrong?

Comment: success : function(response){
   if(response && response != null){
    var logoutResp = response.split(', ');
    if(logoutResp && json.parse(logoutResp[0]).redirectUrl != null){
     window.location.href = json.parse(logoutResp[0]).redirectUrl;
    }
   }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding (from the OP's comments) is that the response is coming back as a string like this: `authResp = '{"redirectUrl":"http:\/\/lumoslocal.heymath.com"}, {"status":"SUCCESS"}'`

Technically this is not valid `JSON` as one big chunk, you'll get an error (test it out below)

```js
JSON.parse('{"redirectUrl":"http:\/\/lumoslocal.heymath.com"}, {"status":"SUCCESS"}')
```

To successfully parse the data (and ultimately get the `redirectUrl` data), follow these steps:

1. split the string with a comma `","` character
2. parse the "first `JSON` element"
3. redirect to extracted redirectUrl

Here's the code for each step:

```js
authResp = '{"redirectUrl":"http:\/\/lumoslocal.heymath.com"}, {"status":"SUCCESS"}';
    
// 1. split the string with a comma character:
let authArr = authResp.split(',');
    
// 2. parse the first JSON element:
let redirectObj = JSON.parse(authArr[0]);

// 3. redirect to extracted redirectUrl
window.location.href = redirectObj.redirectUrl;
```

Or, if you want to parse the entire string into an array of `JSON` objects you can do this:

```js
authResp = '{"redirectUrl":"http:\/\/lumoslocal.heymath.com"}, {"status":"SUCCESS"}';

// create array of json strings, then parse each into separate array elements
authArr = authResp.split(',').map(e => JSON.parse(e));

// Finally, follow @JackBashford's code:
window.location.href = authArr.find(e => e.redirectUrl).redirectUrl;
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Hm6RLtp - I implemented that. Can you please check what is still wrong?

Comment: @AkhilRanjan yeah you have to do all-capital `JSON.parse(...`, not `json` - you're close!

Answer (score 0):

If your two responses are in an array, it's simple, even if they're unordered:

```
var myJSON = [{"redirectUrl": "http:\/\/lumoslocal.heymath.com"}, {"status": "SUCCESS"}];
window.location.href = myJSON.find(e => e.redirectURL).redirectURL;
```

Comment: They aren't in an array.

Comment: The `redirectURL` in =>  `window.location.href = myJSON.find(e => e.redirectURL).redirectURL;` should be `redirectUrl`